# Hero image is a thin stripe in experience fragment

Tags: aem

I wanted to implement a hero image in my website, so I went to Experience fragment and chose the "experience fragment web variation" template and made the hero image with the title.

But when I implemented it to the site, it results in a thin black stripe(it's a night photo so I assume it's just showing the very top).

How do I fix this?

Comment: you can use css.

Comment: Any idea which element to call in?

Comment: Please share exactly what you have tried or, at least, steps to help us replicate the issue so we can help.